# Error while making ng serve Angular 4 (missing module)

Tags: angular, typescript, module

I'm trying to open my project in browser, using ng serve, but everytime i run the command, give me the following error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/esm5/animations.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in 
'/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/platform-
browser/esm5'
resolve '@angular/animations' in 
'/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/platform-
browser/esm5'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: 
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/platform-
browser/package.json (relative path: ./esm5)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
after using description file: 
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/platform-
browser/package.json (relative path: ./esm5)
resolve as module
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/platform-
browser/esm5/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/platform-
browser/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/node_modules 
doesn't exist or is not a directory
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist 
or is not a directory
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a 
directory
/home/easy/Desktop/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
/home/easy/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
/home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
looking for modules in /home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules
using description file: /home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/package.json 
(relative path: ./node_modules)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
after using description file: 
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/package.json (relative path: 
./node_modules)
using description file: 
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/animations/
package.json (relative path: .)
no extension
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration          
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/animations is not 
a file.ts
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration          
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/animations.ts 
doesn't exist.js
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration          
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/animations.js 
doesn't exist
as directory
existing directory
using path: 
/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/animations/index
using description file:
```

/home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/node_modules/@angular/animations/
   package.json (relative path: ./index)    no extension
   Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
   /home/easy/Desktop/wa7shy2/crm/src/@angular/animations/browser.ts 
   doesn't exist.js

I'm pretty sure that the module is installed, checked the paths myself and found all the files that says it's not found, tried uninstalling and installing again, still the same issue, someone tell me what's wrong here.

I'm installing using the command npm install @angular/animations@latest --save

Comment: Are you using Angular 4, or 5? Because your title says 4, but your command will install the latest version of animations, i.e. 5.2.7

Comment: 5.2.7, i checked the package.json, it says thata platform-browser and animations are 5.2.7 but angular is 5.0.0

Comment: its not working, that's why im posting a question -_- thanks for your big support

Comment: Did you generate your app with CLI command? Can you share with us your angular-cli and tsconfig files, it seems that there is a wrong config To o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue, @angular/animations folder was empty, so i copied the missing files from backup @angular folder into it, now it's working well.